# is it possible to use an ipod classic3G as external disk with ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ipod, hfs+

I have an ipod classic 30GB. It is partitioned with Apple HFS.
Can I use it as an external drive with Ubuntu 12.04  LTS?

to sudo fdisk -l I get:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8006 MB, 8006926336 bytes
247 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1021 cylinders, total 15638528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00085342

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    13559807     6778880   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        13561854    15636479     1037313    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        13561856    15636479     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 16.3 GB, 16288579584 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1980 cylinders, total 31813632 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000881d5

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048    31813631    15905792   83  Linux
Note: sector size is 2048 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 30.0 GB, 30005821440 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 7153 cylinders, total 14651280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 2048 = 2048 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048 bytes / 2048 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 2048 bytes / 2048 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

to sudo blkid I get:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="10b8c1cb-1b08-4b58-a312-376ea4206fb6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="969c9b05-a91e-43ed-8fd1-715fdbbf2f71" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="XINUTOP-NAV" UUID="2c574e17-6f0e-4828-b153-ded6a7a03d2f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="693884dd-2694-3072-b912-ed8d6c27728e" LABEL="PamelaM-bM-^@M-^Ys iPod" TYPE="hfsplus"
```

to mount -l I get:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/thierry/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=thierry)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/XINUTOP-NAV type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks) [XINUTOP-NAV]
/dev/sdb3 on /media/Pamela’s iPod type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks) [Pamela’s iPod]
```

Comment: While connected, edit your question and paste the result of these commands: `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid` I am much sure you can use!

Answer (score -1):

You can enable writing to HFS+ in Linux even if you didn't disable journaling. In addition to hfsplus which you already have, you need to have hfsprogs installed:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

Then, use the -o force option:

```
sudo mount -o force /dev/sdX /your/mount/point
```

If the drive has been mounted automatically (as it should be on a desktop system like Ubuntu), you can enable write with

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /mount/point
```

or

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /dev/sdx
```

`/mount/point` would usually be `/media/Your_drive_label /dev/sdx` is your HFS+ device

Use `mount -l` to find which device is already mounted on which mount point.

Comment: Could you detail how to disable journaling?

Comment: I used mount-l to find the mount point for the device (see above), then I installed hfsprogs with: sudo apt-get install hfsprogs. I

Comment: I used mount-l to find the mount point for the device (see above), then I installed hfsprogs with: sudo apt-get install hfsprogs. I then used: sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /dev/sdb3. The device is still read only. I also tried: sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /dev/sdb3/media/Pamela’s iPod an got this: mount: you must specify the filesystem type, now I don't know what the filesystem type is and what to do

Comment: I tried again sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /dev/sdb3" then "mount -l" and got this: "/dev/sdb3 on /media/Pamela’s iPod type hfsplus (rw,nosuid,nodev,force,uhelper=udisks) [Pamela’s iPod]", I still cannot copy files on it...